# R grep find multiple complete words in vector

Tags: r, intersect

I have a vector of strings, say:

```
vect<-c("oxidor magnesio","oxido magnesio","oxido calcio", "oxidante","oxido calcio magnesio","magnesio oxido")
```

I'd like to find the occurences of **both** words, `"oxido"` and `"magnesio"`.
What I'm doing is

```
intersect(grep("\\boxido\\b",vect),grep("\\bmagnesio\\b",vect))
```

But,

1. **Question 1**: is there any *direct* grep command to achieve it?
2. **Question 2**: suppose I want to find occurrences of both words, but in a given order (say, for instance, "oxido" followed by "magnesio", so the correct answer would be `2` and `5`). What would be the command?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit. 
Answer 1: I know that `grepl` is capable of that, e.g.:

```
> grepl("(?=.*\\boxido\\b)(?=.*\\bmagnesio\\b)", vect, perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer 2:

```
> grep("\\boxido\\b.*\\bmagnesio\\b",vect,v=T)
[1] "oxido magnesio"        "oxido calcio magnesio"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried plain `grep` as well but got lost in brackets and question marks :)